# Using parameters in create viewset?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In a specific usecase of my application, I would like to do some logic (varies based on what the user chooses - and thus passed through via the API url) in order to create and return a model.

In my application I have a simple test model and question model (each question has a concept:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    concept = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)


class Test(models.Model):

    num_questions = models.IntegerField()
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

I hoped that user would be able to do a create as such `XXX/api/v1/test/create/Math` and this would return them a test with questions randomly chosen that pertain to math.

in my url I have explicitly called out `path('test/create/<str:concept>', CreateTestView.as_view(), name="test-create="),`

However, when I try and reference this, it does not allow me to pass it in (erroring out with concept is not defined):

```
class CreateTestView(generics.ListCreateAPIView, concept):

    test = Test()

    ... add random questions to test

    queryset = test
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
```

Comment: First of all, **`ListAPIView`** view doesn't allow you to create new instance

Comment: Thanks JPG, have updated for ListCreateAPIView in the above example.

Comment: Ok then, What would you like to do on the endpoint , `/test/create/{concept}/` ? (and on which type request `GET/POST/PATCH/PUT`)?

Comment: So, on a logged in request, I would like to create do two things: 1) create a test that has three random questions that match the {concept} and 2) return this test to the user

Comment: what would be the value of `num_questions` on these cases? Which kind of request are you going to use?

Comment: ideally, number of questions should also be passed in such that /test/create/{concept}/{num_questions} but I wanted to simpify if for teh question. I assume its a get request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want to use the `<str:concept>` param. You need to specify that param in the method definition of the view (post, get, patch,...) where you want
to use that parameter.

```
class CreateTestView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def post(self, request, concept, *args, **kwargs):
        # use concept param

    def get(self, request, concept, *args, **kwargs):
        # use concept param

    def patch(self, request, concept, *args, **kwargs):
        # use concept param

    # all the methods where you want to use the concept param
```